# MapReduce using Tez

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I'm creating a validation tool which checks whether Apache Tez is working or not in hortonworks distribution of Hadoop, in order to do that I need to check whether a simple map reduce program is getting executed on Tez, I could see that a property in `mapred-default.xml` has to be changed.

```
mapreduce.framework.name = yarn-tez (ref: http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.0.2/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap-tez-2.html)
```

I don't want to change any settings of the cluster, so is there any way that I could run MapReduce using Tez without touching `mapred-default.xml`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use "bin/hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar wordcount -Dmapreduce.framework.name=yarn-tez input output".

"-Dkey=value" can be used to override most config properties specified in the *-site.xml files.

Alternatively, you can running native Tez examples for validating the setup ( from tez-examples.jar/tez-mapreduce-examples.jar depending on the Tez version ) instead of relying on running a MapReduce job in tez mode.